# FlowDocument styles from ResourceDictionary are applied, but FontSize and FontFamily is not

Tags: c#, xaml, flowdocument

I have created a FlowDocument dynamically in my code. After displaying it I noticed, that Font size and family does not match the predefined style.

Xaml of my window contains this code to display FlowDocument:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer
    Name="LeftFlowDocumentScrollViewer"
    Height="200"
    />
```

Code behind that fills in the document:

```
var doc = new FlowDocument();

doc.Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
var bigTextStyle = new Style();
bigTextStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.BlueViolet));
bigTextStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal));
bigTextStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Arial")));
bigTextStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, (Double)50));
doc.Resources.Add("BigText", bigTextStyle);

var p = new Paragraph();
doc.Blocks.Add(p);
p.Inlines.Add(new Run("Hello "));

var bigTextRun = new Run("Big text ");
bigTextRun.SetResourceReference(FrameworkElement.StyleProperty, "BigText");
p.Inlines.Add(bigTextRun);

LeftFlowDocumentScrollViewer.Document = doc;
```

Font color is applied correctly which shows that style is applied to the Run element, but font size and font family is not assigned. Why does that happend and how to make it work? It seems that everything else in my FlowDocument works correctly (paragraphs, tables, canvases with drawings...)
Interesting is that if I serialize the FlowDocument object and deserialize it back and then I display it then font size and family is correct!

Here is how the serialized flow document looks like - it looks exactly as defined in the code:

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <FlowDocument.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="IFrameworkInputElement" x:Key="BigText">
            <Style.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary />
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush>#FF8A2BE2</SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <FontWeight>Normal</FontWeight>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <FontFamily>Arial</FontFamily>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <s:Double>50</s:Double>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </FlowDocument.Resources>
    <Paragraph>Hello <Run Style="{DynamicResource BigText}" xml:space="preserve">Big text </Run>
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

Image - how it looks (left) and how it should look like (and looks like after serialize/deserialize magic) (right):
[image: Image - how it looks (left) and how it should look like (and looks like after serialize/deserialize magic) (right)]

Comment: I can not tell, why only part of the properties are applied. However I am pleased to find a solution for coded style definitions that worked (I used it for paragraphs). +1 Thank You